# Diplaying Thumbnails Next to Each other rather than below MYSQL/PHP

Tags: html, css

Morning,

I'm creating a profile page, which I want to display thumbnails next to each other, with overlays that popup with info on a button click. I can get everything to work apart from that the thumbnail pics are displayed in a separate row, whereas I want them side by side.

Without the code for the overlay, they display next to each other, but then the overlay doesn't work. Currently in a catch22...

Any pointers?

Thanks

```
<?php
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY Position,Number");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      echo '<div class="box" ><div id="triggers">',
           '<img src="profile/'.$row['Id'].'.jpg" rel="#mies'.$row['Id'].'"/>',
           '</div>',
           '<div class="simple_overlay" id="mies'.$row['Id'].'" align="center">',
           '<div class="details">',
           '<img src="profile/'.$row['Id'].'l.jpg" />',
           'Name: <b>'.$row['FirstName'].' '.$row['Surname'].'</b></br>',
           'Position: <b>'.$row['Position'].'</b> Number: <b>'.$row['Number'].'</b></br>',
           'Years With Saxons: <b>'.$row['YrsWithSaxons'].'</b></br>',
           'Previous Teams: <b>'.$row['PreviousTeams'].'</b></br>',
           'Favourite NFL Team: <b>'.$row['NFLTeam'].'</b></br>',
           'Favourite NCAA Team: <b>'.$row['NCAATeam'].'</b></br>',

           '</div></div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with PHP or MySQL. The problem lies within you HTML and CSS.

Comment: you should post the HTML output of and the CSS because ass @KemalFadillah mentioned the issue doesn't lie in th PHP/MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might possibly add a bit of styling to your css for the "box" element.
add "float:left;" and possibly a 'margin-right: 10px;" to space them a bit if you like.
be sure to include a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the last box in your html.

Answer (score 0):

You want to either float the .box elements, or set them to display as inline-block.

```
display: inline-block;
```

or

```
float: left;
```